# How to fill an input value with pure javascript in a ReactJS stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input that is not an element of a `form` I want to fill the value of this input with a text using `name` tag.

I tried `document.getElementsByName('input_name').value='Text'` but this is not working

The `React - JSX` input is:

`<input type='text' name='input_name'/>`

Comment: If you're creating this DOM element via React, is there a reason you specifically want to manipulate the element directly like that instead of handling the value in the React component?

Comment: @cubrr I am very new to react , this code is inside a react component but i am just thinking if there's a way to fill the value without using `state`, i want to use pure javascript if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByName returns a collection, so you need to grab the first item:

```
document.getElementsByName('input_name')[0].value='Text'
```

Comment: i thought this will only work when the input is an element of a form